# python - Composer plugin menu catch-22

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, print-composer, qgis-2.12

a plugin for the Print Composer checks if the current project has at least one Composer when loading to avoid the error when creating the menu on a Composer that doesn't exist. However, once the plugin is installed and QGIS starts up, it does it with an empty project that doesn't have any Composers, so the menu is not created. The current situation is that once I'm working on a project with a Composer, I have to open "Manage and install plugins" and reload the plugin to create its menu. Any workarounds?